# Run python script using spark-submit on windows 7

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to submit a python script using spark-submit on windows 7. I'm using spark 2.3.0 built for hadoop 2.7 . The python script is supposed to read data from a csv file and plot graphs. is it possible to run such a script using spark-submit? In the python script I included this block of code for spark context.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
APP_NAME = 'kineticPCA'
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
conf = conf.setMaster('spark://192.168.xx.xxx:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

This is the how submit the job on command prompt, on the spark bin directory

```
spark-submit G:/guru orders/pca kinetics/files/kineticPCA.py
```

This is the error I get:

> Error: Cannot load main class from JAR G:/guru with URI G. Please
>   s through --class.
>   Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output

[image]

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

use this command 
.\bin\spark-submit \guruorders\pcakinetics\files\kineticPCA.py